# is there a system-wide "extension" to /etc/services that does not get replaced on package updates?

Tags: debian, networking, apt, package-management, services

I know how to use `/etc/services` but if I change it and the `inetd` package is later updated via `apt-get` to a new default one, my changes are gone (happened to me on a `apt-get dist-upgrade` from Debian Wheezy to Jessie). They are saved in a backup, but I still have to re-integrate my changes or alternartivley miss out on the new defaults from the package manager (by skipping the install of the new default version).

Is there a way to have a user-generated system wide "extension" to `/etc/services` that gets loaded as well and contains only my changes so that the configuration does not get destroyed with a package update?

I'm working on Debian Jessie, if relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/services` is a [conffile](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-conffile), so if you modify it locally and a new package version is installed with a modified version, dpkg will ask you whether to keep your version or install the new one. Unfortunately, it won't give you an easy way to merge your changes.

You can [divert](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/118/Replacing_binaries_with_dpkg-divert) the package-provided `/etc/services` and provide your own.

```
dpkg-divert --add --local --rename --divert /etc/services.debian /etc/services
```

If you want to concatenate your own entries or otherwise transform the Debian file, you can run a hook script when APT finishes its job. Declare the script in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local-etc-merge`

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"cat /etc/services.local /etc/services.debian >/etc/services"}
```

Alternatively, you can make `/etc/services` [invoke a command when read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66990/create-a-virtual-file-that-is-actually-a-command) (that's overkill unless you modify `/etc/services.local` very often).

Comment: Post-Invoke seems pretty good. In `/etc/services` is there a way to say "`include services.locale`" so that I only have to change one file between package updates and only need to `cat >` the include command?

Comment: @FooBar There's no include directive. But with my solution you don't need to change any file on a package update, you only need to do this one-time setup and to re-run `cat /etc/services.local /etc/services.debian >/etc/services` when you change `/etc/services.local`.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because this provides an actual workaround. But the other answers also got a +1, because they teached me nice things.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to come up in various bugtrackers from time to time: [Debian #46049](https://bugs.debian.org/46049), [Debian #711001](https://bugs.debian.org/711001), [RH #133683](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=133683#c3). But none of these seem to be implemented.

To recap: the *Name Service Switch* reads `/etc/nsswitch.conf` where to look for e.g. `services` information:

```
$ strace -f -e open,stat getent services > /dev/null
[...]
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.3.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/var/lib/misc/DB_CONFIG", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/misc/services.db", 0x7ffd79d77060) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/services", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

This `libnss_db.so.2` could only be found because I installed [libnss-db](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libnss-db) earlier. <s>So, if one manages to create a [Berkeley DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) database in `/var/lib/misc/services.db` with additional service names, this could work.</s>

**Update:** with `libnss-db` (Debian/unstable here), this is indeed possible:

```
$ grep ^[A-Z] /etc/default/libnss-db 
ETC = /etc/local
DBS = services
VAR_DB = /var/lib/misc
AWK = awk
MAKEDB = makedb --quiet

$ cat /etc/local/services
# Local services
foobar          1234/tcp                        # Foo
barbaz          4321/udp

$ make
services... done.

$ getent services | wc -l
559

$ getent services foobar barbaz
foobar                1234/tcp
barbaz                4321/udp
```

And since `/etc/local` is [not](https://packages.debian.org/file:/etc/local) a registered configuration directory, it should not be touched by any upgrade process

Otherwise, these pathnames seem to be hardcoded and can only be changed/extended in a recompile, hence the wishlist tickets mentioned above.

```
$ strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2 | grep services
/etc/services
```

Note: there's also an [libnss-extrausers](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libnss-extrausers) package, which seems to provide additional files for NSS, but only for `passwd`, `shadow` and `group` information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way of doing this. One option would be to "Hold" the `netbase` package so that it doesn't get updated automatically.

```
echo "netbase hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

Another option might be to declare an `/etc/services.local` and submit a patch to the `netbase` maintainer that merged this file and its own `/etc/services`. I don't see that this would be too difficult except that a modified sort/merge would be required to understand `#` comment lines.