# Connect Symbolic Link to program or script that returns a file

Tags: symlink, cygwin, hadoop

I wanted to know if I can make a symlink to a file say in a Database.

This is a wild guess, but is it possible to intercept the link-follow say using a C function and then let function return the file say in a stream.

Cygwin does similar intercept for symlink follow, when we require symlinks in windows right, by reading a .lnk and another associate file for the rest of the dat which is supposed to be in a symlink and then do the follow.

My real scenario: I wanted to see if I can get a symlink to follow a file to a HDFS file which I can say pull using its API.

Comment: a symbolic link that return data looks to me as a driver. for instance `/dev/sr0` which "point" to DVD drive, and return error if no DVD. Now, testing if a file exists using an API shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: @Archemar thanx for the point. But, do you think fuse as meuh mentioned is the right approach - without, going to the kernel level, resolving at user-space.

Comment: See also [Create a virtual file that is actually a command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66990/create-a-virtual-file-that-is-actually-a-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 2 mechanisms readily available in *Linux* (but probably not in cygwin). There is the **fuse** filesystem, see `man fuse`, which allows you to implement a filesystem in user-space. For example, `curlftpfs` (see its man page) converts file accesses into `curl` ftp calls.

Then there is the **fanotify** system call, which allows you to intercept calls made to open or read a file, and substitute or manipulate the data. See `man fanotify`.