# Recover from faking /proc/meminfo

Tags: bash, shell-script, swap, proc, meminfo

So, without really thinking too much, I ran this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SWAP="${1:-512}"
NEW="$[SWAP*1024]"; TEMP="${NEW//?/ }"; OLD="${TEMP:1}0"
sed "/^Swap\(Total\|Free\):/s,$OLD,$NEW," /proc/meminfo > /etc/fake_meminfo
mount --bind /etc/fake_meminfo /proc/meminfo
```

from here: http://linux-problem-solver.blogspot.com.ee/2013/08/create-fake-swap-in-openvz-vps-if-you-get-swapon-failed-operation-not-permitted-error.html

It worked really well for lying about my swap-space, but now I'd like good old commands like

```
free -m
```

to work again, but /proc/meminfo is totally empty and the server doesn't seem to know anything about it's RAM any more, even with atop or somesuch.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does it work to simply `umount /etc/fake_meminfo`?

Comment: Maybe it would have worked? I failed to mention I already tried fixing it by running a bunch of mount/unmount commands, just not the right one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just unmount it: `umount /proc/meminfo`

All those programs (`free`, `top`, `atop`, etc.) have to get their information from somewhere. And that somewhere is `/proc/meminfo`.

If you want to provide fake information for one program, run it in a [mount namespace](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/):

```
$ unshare -m bash
$$ mount --bind … /proc/meminfo
$$ myprogram
```

If you want to lie only about the swap space, make the fake `meminfo` file a [dynamic file via a FUSE filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66990/create-a-virtual-file-that-is-actually-a-command/66992#66992). (Note: a named pipe also works, but only if it's accessed by a single program at a time.)