# How can I fake the amount of installed RAM for a specific program in Linux?

Tags: linux, ram

I'm running [BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/) on my old netbook, which only has 2 GB of RAM onboard, which isn't enough for some tasks to run. As in, they refuse to, seeing how low on RAM the device is.

I have zRAM with backing_dev and zstd algorithm enabled, so in reality, lack of memory is never an issue, and in especially tough cases I can always just use `systemd-run --scope -p` (I have successfully ran programs that demanded +16 GB of RAM using this)

How can I make BOINC think that my laptop has more than 2 GB of RAM installed, so that I could run those demanding tasks?

Comment: I don't how does BOINK check for amount of available RAM, it may just read `/proc/meminfo` but could you start from creating a swap file if you have enough disk space available?

Comment: Or something like here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258145/recover-from-faking-proc-meminfo

Comment: If that program is checking the avail memory via `/proc/meminfo` you can simply edit the binary and replace the `/proc/meminfo` with some other path having the same length. Eg. `perl -pe 's,/proc/meminfo,/etc/bmeminfo,' -i /path/to/that/binary`. This is MUCH better than having to set up namespaces or mess up your system in other ways. With a little bit of assembly knowledge, you can also change that check to always return true, so you don't even have to create a fake `meminfo` file.

Comment: Do you mean [BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some thinking, I did this:

Started with `nano /proc/meminfo`

Changed `MemTotal`, `MemFree`, `MemAvailable`, `SwapTotal` and `SwapFree` to desired values and saved to ~./meminfo

Gave the user boinc password `sudo passwd boinc` and shell -- `sudo nano /etc/passwd` , found the line `boinc:x:129:141:BOINC core client,,,:/var/lib/boinc-client:/usr/sbin/nologin` and changed the `/usr/sbin/nologin` part to `/bin/bash`

Then I faked RAM info using examples from here [Recover from faking /proc/meminfo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258145/recover-from-faking-proc-meminfo)

```
unshare -m bash    #unshares mount spaces, for specific program "bash" only (and for whatever you want to launch from it)
mount --bind ~./meminfo /proc/meminfo      #substitutes real meminfo data with fake one
```

and confirmed with `free` that it worked

```
          total        used        free         shared     buff/cache  available
Mem:     2321456       21456     2300000           0           0     2300000
Swap:     5000000     1000000     4000000
```

Then switched to user `su - boinc` and just launched the program with

```
boinc --check_all_logins --redirectio --dir /var/lib/boinc-client
```

BOINC Manager can be launched then as usual

Total success, tasks which previously refused to run, started to download and then ran with no complications

Answer (score 52):

Create a fake `meminfo` and mount it over an original `/proc/meminfo`:

```
$ mkdir fake-meminfo && cd fake-meminfo
$ cp /proc/meminfo .
$ chmod +w meminfo
$ sed -Ei 's,^MemTotal:        [0-9]+ kB,MemTotal:        8839012 kB,' meminfo   # replace 8839012 with an amount of RAM you want to pretend you have
$ free -m  # check how much RAM you have now
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7655        1586        3770         200        2298        5373
$ sudo mount --bind meminfo /proc/meminfo                                 
$ free -m  # check how much RAM you pretend to have after replacing /proc/meminfo
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           8631        2531        3800         201        2299        5403
$ sudo umount /proc/meminfo # restore an original /proc/meminfo
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7655        1549        3806         200        2299        5410
```

You can also run the above commands in a mount namespace isolated from
the rest of the system. References:
[Recover from faking /proc/meminfo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258145/recover-from-faking-proc-meminfo)

Comment: `mount --bind meminfo /proc/meminfo` says `mount point /proc/meminfo is not a directory` in CentOS docker