# Manipulate the result of uname?

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, hardware, proc

Is it possible to fool Linux what CPU, the amount of memory etc it runs on? I have a NAS running an obscure custom Linux distribution (Seagate's internal) that requires a certain hardware to enable a function I want to use but my device doesn't fit those requirements.

I don't think there is a technical reason for this limitation, rather it has to do with marketing and market segmentation, and was thinking that maybe I could manipulate what `uname`, `/proc/cpuinfo` and similar are returning to make the admin interface allow me to enable this function (volume encryption) that way.

Is this possible? I have root access.

Comment: Fake RAM - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581058/how-can-i-fake-the-amount-of-installed-ram-for-a-specific-program-in-linux

Comment: What `uname` prints memory information?

Comment: @muru: the way I understand the question is that OP wants to fake both amount of RAM installed and CPU type.

Comment: I came across [this link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220357/fake-output-of-cpuid-instruction).

Comment: @KGIII Seems too complicated. Doubt I have the necessary tools on my limited version of Linux.