# Is there a Linux system call to create a “view” of a range of a file?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

Does Linux provide a system call which can create a "view" of a limited byte range of a backing file? I'm envisioning something that for example would act on an open file descriptor and either modify it or generate a new file descriptor where file offsets are relative to the beginning of the range and end at the end of the range.

The use-case would be to limit a non-cooperating subprocess to accessing only a particular portion of an input file.

Comment: See also [Create a virtual file that is actually a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66990/create-a-virtual-file-that-is-actually-a-command)

Comment: @Gilles I was avoiding a pipe (named or otherwise) because I wanted to avoid the extra copy of data through userspace, and thought I'd need the subprocess to seek arbitrarily in its constrained input.  But now that you've mentioned it, a pipe plus the `splice()` system call seems like it would be nearly right for the stream case.

Comment: While the accepted answer works, it's not really a "system call" as the question asked. For system calls, the `mmap()` call comes to mind, as long as the subprocess is spawned from the process that does the mapping...

Comment: See also mandatory file locking where you could lock a region of the file so that process could not read or write it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use a loop device. This approach does have two requirements which may make it less useful: you need to be root to set it up, and the non-cooperating subprocess must be able to write to a block device. Oh, and it doesn’t deal with conflicting changes.

To set the loop device up, run

```
losetup -o 1024 --sizelimit 2048 --show -f yourfile
```

replacing `1024`, `2048` and `yourfile` with appropriate values — `-o` specifies the start offset, `--sizelimit` the size (counting from the offset). Note that `sizelimit` has to be a multiple of 512.

This will output the name of the loop device which has been set up; adjust the permissions as necessary, and give it to your non-cooperating sub-process. When you no longer need the device, delete it with

```
losetup -d /dev/loopN
```

replacing `N` as appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean with conflicting changes? Do you mean writes that come through the loop device not being in sync with direct writes to the backing file?

Comment: Not 100% what I wanted, but in the absence of anything closer I'll take it.  Thanks!

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, I mean that there needs to be some “agreement” between the processes about who is allowed to write. (It can be simple enough — if the “parent” process doesn’t write while the loop device is set up for the non-cooperating subprocess, everything will be fine.)

Comment: @llasram right, I know this isn’t perfect; the FIFO approach in Gilles’ link is interesting to look at too.